Next.JS routing to dynamic pages with router.push() not rendering correctly
The main problem is the navbar component not being visible on the page when using route.push() because it seems like the rest of the page including the footer are showing up.
I am trying to route to a dynamicly generated page in my next.js application by entering a search string in a search bar component. Router.push() seems to route me to the correct url but the correct content is only rendered once I refresh the page manually then.
My search bar component:
'use client'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'; 
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const SearchBar = () => {
  const [city, setCity] = useState('');
  const { push } = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
     push(`/search/${city}`);
  }, [city]);

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center items-center mt-8">
      <input 
        type="text" 
        placeholder="Search for your city" 
        className="w-full max-w-md p-4 rounded-l-lg shadow-lg focus:ring focus:ring-opacity-50 border-t mr-[-1px] border-b border-l border-gray-300 focus:outline-none"
        value={city}
        onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button 
        type="button" 
        className="bg-red-500 text-white px-6 py-4 rounded-r-lg shadow-lg hover:bg-red-600 transition duration-300"
        onClick={() => push}
      >
        Search
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;

And this is my dynamic page located at /app/search/[city]/page.tsx
import { Restaurant } from "@/app/_interfaces/restaurant";
import { get_restaurants_by_city } from "@/app/_utils/api.service";
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";

export default async function Page({ params }: { params: { city: string } }) {
  const restaurants: Restaurant[] = await get_restaurants_by_city(params.city)
  if(restaurants.length == 0){
    return notFound()
  }
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <div className="navbar">
        <a href="/">Rate your favorite restaurant</a>
        <a href="/regional_ratings">Leaderboard</a>
      </div>
      <h1>Best restaurant in {params.city}</h1>
        <div className="results-container">
          {restaurants.map((restaurant) => (
              <div key={restaurant.id} className="result-item">
                <h2>{restaurant.name} - {(restaurant.google_rating)}</h2>
                <p>{restaurant.street}, {restaurant.zip_code} {restaurant.city}</p>
                <p>Rating: {restaurant.google_rating}</p>
                <button>Vote</button>
              </div>
            ))
          }
        </div>
    </main>
  );
}

Im guessing there is either a better way to route to dynamic pages or I am missing something here.
I already tried the redirect() function but couldn't get it to work properly and the handleNavigation function like this:
const handleNavigation = () => {
    router.push(´/search/${city}´)
    router.refresh()
  };

This handleNavigation funciton worked partially but it wouldn't load the page with all its html it seemed. The navbar was missing for instance.
EDIT:
By using this approach: (also mentioned by @Dhruv)
const handleNavigation = () => {
    router.push(´/search/${city}´)
  };

I get to be routed to the correct page but it doesn't render the navbar in layout.tsx whereas when manually routing to the url /search/{city_name} the page is rendered with the navbar.
app/layout.tsx for clarity:
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import Footer from "./_components/Footer/Footer";
import Navbar from "./_components/Navbar/Navbar";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function RootLayout({
  children, }: Readonly<{ children: React.ReactNode;}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
      <Navbar/>
      <main>
        {children}
      </main>
      <Footer/>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


First thing first,
U r using onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
Which means each letter u type the state will be update, and the state will update then each time use effect will work,that means however the router works (Which is not working) it will redirect to the page, means u can only type one letter, i recommend u to use onBlur method onBlur={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}, it will only work after u click out of your input box anywhere...
Second thing second,
I think u r using router in wrong way, idk but try this method, it might work...
const [city, setCity] = useState('');
const router = useRouter(); //Instead of 'const { push } = useRouter();'

const handleSearch = () => {
    if (city.trim() !== '') {
      router.push(`/search/${city}`); //And then this should work i guess
    }
  }
//Your remaining code...


This approach is similar to the approach I already tried, which worked partially. I see that this is the correct approach but the page im redirected too seems to not be rendered with the layout.tsx file in app/layout.tsx opposed to it being rendered with the correct layout when Im manually directing to the url

You should really improve the grammar.

dear @Andrea, Thanks for your advice, m not native or fluent in english, and i answered those things which i knew, and there is none of your business...
